# crossrider toolbar appear on top of the webpage?

Tags: css, crossrider

here is the link of crossrider toolbar extension demo

[click here](http://crossrider.com/apps/12317/ide)

it's a demo of the toolbar and it is showing over of the website.

so what is the solution of that?

i've tried to change it's css which is

```
$('#xr-crossrider-example').css({
    'background-color':'#2CB7F4',
    height:'24px',
    margin: 0,
    padding: 0,
    position:'fixed',
    right:0,
    top:0,
    width:'100%',
    'z-index':'999'
});
```

Comment: please describe your problem, it is not clear what are you asking.. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use in the your CSS selector select the bar, and make it stick on top of your window using `position: fixed;`

Something like this:

```
.app_header_top {
    position: fixed;
}
```

Comment: please double check, using chrome inspector I see .app_header_site_dropdowns .app_header_site_crossrider{ position:relative;} you should force it with position: fixed !important;

Comment: try using position: fixed !important;